# JIRA Query Language display result

Tags: php, jira-rest-api, jql

I want to display the issue's name, key, created date, resolved date and the team. How can I do that?

I have created the JQL in index.php.

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

`use JiraRestApi\Issue\IssueService;

    $jql = 'project in (MGBUGS) AND resolved >= startOfWeek("-6") AND resolved <= endOfWeek("-5") AND "MaGIC Team" = Tech';

    try {
        $issueService = new IssueService();

        $ret = $issueService->search($jql);
        var_dump($ret);
    } catch (JiraException $e) {
        $this->assertTrue(false, 'testSearch Failed : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
?>`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your issueService.search method is implemented.

Assuming it uses the [POST /api/2/search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest) REST resource then you can specify in the body of the request which fields you're interested in.  Your results will then include those fields.

Example body:

```
{
  "jql": "project = HSP",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 15,
  "fields": [
    "summary",
    "status",
    "assignee"
  ],
  "fieldsByKeys": false
}
```